# buttons and levels

Tags: android

I have a class where I add some buttons in code. I am adding this button click on my second button. I want to adding this buttons one above second. I mean: I cick on the button and first button is adding to layout, I click second time and this second button add but he must be uder this first. Under I mean that first button cover second and I can't see second.. I don't want to see that second button. I click third time and third button is adding under second button. How I can do that in code? I know How add buttons but I don't know how to do first button was above second.

Comment: This depends on the layout and layout params of your layout and the first button. Can you show your code? Btw. I would recommend to change the visibility of the first button to INVISIBLE or GONE instead of putting multiple buttons on top of each other.

Comment: I know that I can use Invisible or gone but I need to do that in this way.

Comment: I see, ok. Generally your second button will be on the same position as the first one, when you use the same parameters - relative to their parents (LinearLayout). If you could post your code please, then it will become clearer for the reader to understand you and perhaps someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice adding all the buttons that you need within your XML layout, then for the buttons you do not want to be visible on first load add the following:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Then within you code whenever you want your button to view just add the following line of code within your onClickListener:

```
// Getting you button form your xml layout
Button testBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
// Set visibility of button here
testBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
// To hide the button again simply use this
testBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I can't do that. I need add this buttons to linear layout in this way. I know about gone and invisible but I need to do that in this way

Comment: Ok I am not entirly sure what you are trying to achieve, however you could try using some sort of private int, which keeps a count of the button clicks and then pulls the relevent button in?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RelativeLayout` for parent layout.
And every time you click the button, create a new `Button` and add it to your parent layout with:

```
addView(YOUR_NEWLY_CREATED_BUTTON, 0)
```

function.  This will add your button to your layout as first child. Which means it will be `under` other buttons that is child of your `Relative Layout`

And if your `created` buttons have same `width` and `height`, added buttons won't be visible

Hope this helps